# Counting right triangles: how to improve Time Complexity?

Tags: c++, optimization

Here's the question I am working on:

> N points are placed in the coordinate plane.
>
> Write a program that calculates how many ways we can choose three
>   points so that they form a right triangle with legs parallel to the
>   coordinate axes.

A right triangle has one 90-degree internal angle. The legs of a right triangle are its two shorter sides.

Here's how I organized my code.

For every point, I checked other point. If two points had matching x coordinates and different y coordinates, I looked through the points to find a point with same y coordinate as the new point and different x. If found, I checked if the right angled hypotenus checks out in the three points.

Similarly, I repeated a modification of this for two points with matching y coordinates and different x.

The program works, but exceeds time complexity and I'm not sure how to reduce it.

Here's my code:

```
double distwithoutroot(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
    int xdist = pow((x2 - x1),2);
    int ydist = pow((y2 - y1),2);
    return  xdist + ydist;
}

int main() {
    int noofpoints;

    cin >> noofpoints;
    int xs[100000];
    int ys[100000];
    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < noofpoints; i++) {
        cin >> xs[i] >> ys[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < noofpoints; i++) {
        int main_x_point = xs[i];
        int main_y_point = ys[i];

        for (int j = 0; j < noofpoints; j++) {
            int checkmatchx = xs[j];
            int checkmatchy = ys[j];

            if (main_x_point == checkmatchx && main_y_point != checkmatchy) {

                for (int k = 0; k < noofpoints; k++) {
                    int secondcheckx = xs[k];
                    int secondchecky = ys[k];

                    if (checkmatchy == secondchecky && checkmatchx != secondcheckx) {
                        int hypotenus = distwithoutroot(main_x_point, main_y_point, secondcheckx, secondchecky);

                        int perpendicular = distwithoutroot(main_x_point, main_y_point, checkmatchx, checkmatchy);
                        int base = distwithoutroot(secondcheckx, secondchecky, checkmatchx, checkmatchy);
                        if (hypotenus== ( perpendicular+ base )) {
                            count += 1;
                            }
                        }
                }
            }

            else if (main_y_point == checkmatchy && main_x_point != checkmatchx) {
                for (int k = 0; k < noofpoints; k++) {
                    int secondcheckx = xs[k];
                    int secondchecky = ys[k];
                    if (checkmatchx == secondcheckx && checkmatchy != secondchecky) {
                        int hypotenus = distwithoutroot(main_x_point, main_y_point, secondcheckx, secondchecky);
                        int base = distwithoutroot(main_x_point, main_y_point, checkmatchx, checkmatchy);
                        int perpendicular = distwithoutroot(secondcheckx, secondchecky, checkmatchx, checkmatchy);
                        if (hypotenus == (perpendicular + base)) {
                            count += 1;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }


        }

        cout<<count;

    }
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to CodeReview.

Comment: You want https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Get 3 line equations with three points, check if two of the lines are parallel to either axes ( eg y+5=0 or ay+b =0 in general), if still they qualify, check for pythagorus.

Answer (score 2):

You only need to put all points in two maps, by x and by y. Running time is reduced to O(N)*O(T), T is maximum of triangles at the same corner.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding the idea in [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51481547/509868).

Note that there is no need to check the Pythagorean Theorem. If the triangle has one horizontal leg and one vertical leg, it is a right triangle. To count the number of such triangles, you only need to have the number of points whose X and Y coordinate are equal to any value.

So, a code sketch:

```
std::map<int, int> map_x; // for each X, counts the points for which xs = X
std::map<int, int> map_y; // for each Y, counts the points for which ys = Y

for (int i = 0; i < noofpoints; i++)
    ++map_x[xs[i]];

for (int i = 0; i < noofpoints; i++)
    ++map_x[ys[i]];

for (int i = 0; i < noofpoints; i++)
    count += (map_x[xs[i]] - 1) * (map_y[ys[i]] - 1);
```

Explanation on the last loop:

It iterates over all points, and counts the number of right triangles for which this point is at the right angle position.

For each point, it knows how many points have the same X and how many points have the same Y (have to subtract 1 to exclude the same point). Each combination of these gives a suitable triangle.

BTW some of the triangles might be degenerate (have zero area); also, if some points appear twice, some triangles may be identical. I don't think you should exclude these from counting.

Comment: Unordered maps should be here as you don't need any orderings in keys.